# Can I get an image that have orientation 2?

Tags: image-processing

**I need to test image orientation 2 photo in my website. But I don't get any orientation as 2 (mirror).**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you juste need to add a little bit of css, just as shown in W3School :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_image.asp

Comment: Sorry.I need only image that already have image orientation 2 . I don't want to flip sir.I need Photo.